# unable to trace XML API error

Tags: php, xml, web-services, rest

i am trying to integrate a shipping API but it is not working and not returning any erro either. What i am trying to achieve is, I sending customer shipping data in xml format to an API URL , it will create a shipment and return me shipping tracking number. But it is not working and unable to trace any error, if there is any. Can you please help review code and tell me if there is any issue.

INFO: that is piece of code, as i get it working i will integrate it with magento shipment methods.

Here is my code..

```
$xmlns = [
  'soap' => 'http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope',     
  't' => 'http://tempuri.org/'
];
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement(
  '<?xml version = "1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" />'
);
$body = $xml->addChild("soap:Body", null, $xmlns['soap']);

$shipInfo = $body->addChild('InsertData', null, $xmlns['t']);
$shipInfo->addChild('auserName', "testuser");
$shipInfo->addChild('apassword', "testpass");

$shipInfo->addChild('acostCenterCode', "CC001");
$shipInfo->addChild('aconsigneeName', "Shipping TESTING");
$shipInfo->addChild('aconsigneeAddress', "Ship Demo Address");
$shipInfo->addChild('aconsigneeMobNo', "01801234577");
$shipInfo->addChild('aconsigneeEmail', "shiptesting@testing.com");
$shipInfo->addChild('aoriginCityName', "NY");
$shipInfo->addChild('adestinationCityName', "CA");
$shipInfo->addChild('apieces', "1");
$shipInfo->addChild('aweight', "1");
$shipInfo->addChild('acodAmount', "0");
$shipInfo->addChild('acustRefNo', "WebW");
$shipInfo->addChild('aproductDetails', "Test Product");
$shipInfo->addChild('afragile', "0");
$shipInfo->addChild('aservices', "0");
$shipInfo->addChild('aremarks', "Testing API services");
$shipInfo->addChild('ainsuranceValue', "0");


$xmlRequest = $xml->asXML();


try {
  //header('Content-type: text/xml');
  $testUrl = "http://255.255.255.255:3232";

  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $testUrl);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xmlRequest);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,0);
  $xmlResponse = curl_exec ($ch);

  $debugData['result'] = $xmlResponse;
} catch (Exctption $e){
  $debugData['result'] = array('error' => $e->getMessage(), 'code' => curl_errno($ch));
  $xmlResponse = '';
}
print($debugData['result']);

curl_close($ch);
```

Thanks,